# Chromium / Google Chrome sends double requests

Tags: java, google-chrome, jakarta-ee, video-streaming

I am a beginner in Java EE and I deal with the following problem: when streaming a video in response both Chromium and Google Chrome send duplicated GET requests and java.io.IOException is thrown. There is everything fine on Firefox. Here is my simple doGet method code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    File video = new File(PATH_TO_VIDEO);
    try {
        ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(Files.readAllBytes(video.toPath()));
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with this approach or is it a browser bug? I was reading about multiple Chrome requests, but I didn't find a rewarding answer. I have disabled predicting network actions in Chrome, but it doesn't help.

Thanks!